# Bootstrap form layout , 2-column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, forms, bootstrap-4

i´m new in using bootstrap (version 4) and my task is write code for this form [form layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMcLV.png), but i can´t find right way. Can you help me please. Thanks.

Comment: You're new, so I'll lay this out for you. StackOverflow isn't the place to come for homework questions. You need to start by doing some research and reading docs, in this case about Bootstrap layouts, and come to SO with your attempted solution. Then, we assist by filling in the blanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this...

```
<div class="container p-3">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
      <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2" placeholder="Name">
      <input type="email" class="form-control mb-2" placeholder="Email">
      <input type="phone" class="form-control mb-2" placeholder="Phone">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
      <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Text Area" rows="4"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container p-3">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2" placeholder="Name">
      <input type="email" class="form-control mb-2" placeholder="Email">
      <input type="phone" class="form-control mb-2" placeholder="Phone">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Text Area" rows="4"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```